# Оплата голосами в приложении ВКонтакте (API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Ищу примеров или подробных мануалов по написанию приложений для ВК, и желательно пример для оплаты некоторых функций приложения.
Хотя, больше всего последнее интересует.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите готовый с мануалом, почитайте http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=Flash-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F